# Iterating through PyMongo cursor throws InvalidBSON: year is out of range

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am using PyMongo to simply iterate over a Mongo collection, but I'm struggling with handling large Mongodb date objects.

For example, if I have some data in a collection that looks like this:

```
"bad_data" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "id01",
                "label" : "bad_data",
                "value" : "exist",
                "type" : "String",
                "lastModified" : ISODate("2018-06-01T10:04:35.000Z"),
                "expires" : Date(9223372036854775000)
            }
        ]
```

I will do something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, database, cursor, collection
client = MongoClient('localhost')
db = client['db1']
db.authenticate('user', 'pass', source='admin')
collection = db['collection']
for i in collection:
    # do something with i
```

and get the error `InvalidBSON: year 292278994 is out of range`

Is there any way I can handle dealing with this rediculous `Date()` object without bson falling over? I realise that having such a date in Mongodb is crazy but there is nothing I can do about this as it's not my data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There actually is a section in the PyMongo FAQ about this very topic:

> [Why do I get OverflowError decoding dates stored by another language’s driver?](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#why-do-i-get-overflowerror-decoding-dates-stored-by-another-language-s-driver)
>
> PyMongo decodes BSON datetime values to instances of Python’s `datetime.datetime`. Instances of `datetime.datetime` are limited to years between `datetime.MINYEAR` (usually 1) and `datetime.MAXYEAR` (usually 9999). Some MongoDB drivers (e.g. the PHP driver) can store BSON datetimes with year values far outside those supported by `datetime.datetime`.

So the basic constraint here is on the `datetime.datetime` type as implemented for the mapping from BSON by the driver, and though it might be "ridiculous" it's valid for other languages to create such a date value.

As pointed to in the FAQ your general workarounds are:

1. Deal with the offending BSON Date. Whilst valid to store, it possibly was not the "true" intention of whomever/whatever stored it in the first place.
2. Add a "date range" condition to your code to filter "out of range" dates:

   ```
   result = db['collection'].find({ 
     'expires': { '$gte': datetime.min, '$lte': datetime.max }
   })
   for i in result:
     # do something with i
   ```
3. Omit the offending date field in projection if you don't need the data in further processing:

   ```
   result = db['collection'].find({  }, projection={ 'expires': False })
   for i in result:
     # do something with i
   ```

Certainly `'expires'` as a name suggests the original intent of the value was a date so far into the future that it was never going to come about, with the original author of that data ( and very possibly current code still writing it ) not being aware of the "Python" date constraint. So it's probably quite safe to "lower" that number in all documents and where any code is still writing it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have also figured out a way you can iterate over the result and skip any results that return `InvalidBSON` by calling the `__getitem__` function.

Comment: @grinferno - any chance you have an example of this check?

Comment: This is good but what if the field is dynamic.  Would be nice to have a way to omit problem fields unknown or create a custom decoder.

Comment: The link is broken here. The FAQ is now here: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-get-overflowerror-decoding-dates-stored-by-another-language-s-driver

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with pymongo query.
when I tried to query my data I got this Error:

```
year 53427 is out of range
```

because some of my values were in Unix time and some in IOS time.

my solution:

1. first mark the UNIX time with 1 and normal time with 0 by condition for Date greater than a future date (2023)

```
{$addFields: {
    Unix_time_index: {$cond: 
        { if: { $gt: [ "$mytime", ISODate("2023-12-12T00:00:00.000Z") ] },
          then: 1,
          else: 0 }},
        }},
```

2. then change my time to a Long type number (only for the UNIX time):

```
{$addFields:{
    mytime: {$cond:
        { if: { $eq: [ "$Unix_time_index", 1 ] },
          then: {$toLong: "$mytime"},
          else: "$mytime" }},
        }},
```

3. then divide the long unix time by 1000:

```
{$addFields:{
    mytime: {$cond:
        { if: { $eq: [ "$Unix_time_index", 1 ] },
          then: { $divide: [ "$mytime",1000 ] },
          else: "$mytime" }},
                }},
```

4. and at the end convert the long unix number into a regular number:

```
{$addFields:{
mytime: {$cond: 
        { if: { $eq: [ "$Unix_time_index", 1 ] },
          then: {$toDate: "$mytime"},
          else: "$mytime" }}
                }},
```

results:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606b5d48ab86b4002130f944"),
    "mytime" : ISODate("2021-06-18T21:52:51.000Z"),
    "before" : Date(1624053171000000),
    "Unix_time_index" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606b5d48ab86b4002130f944"),
    "mytime" : ISODate("2021-06-18T21:52:47.000Z"),
    "before" : Date(1624053167000000),
    "Unix_time_index" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606b5d48ab86b4002130f944"),
    "mytime" : ISODate("2022-01-27T23:44:46.000Z"),
    "before" : ISODate("2022-01-27T23:44:46.000Z"),
    "Unix_time_index" : 0.0
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue :

As Neil mentionnned and I quote :

> PyMongo decodes BSON datetime values to instances of Python’s datetime.datetime. Instances of datetime.datetime are limited

So After looking closely at my object, I've noticed some date object are like this :  `0000:12:30T00:00:00`

In my case, the best approach is to set a validation prior to inserting document into the collection, so if the date is 0 , setting it to 1970 solved the issue

[image]