# How to insert documents with wrong value to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm trying to insert documents with wrong value to MongoDB with purpose to test PyMongo library.

Here is the screenshot of the document I want to save to my collection. The wrong value is dateOfBirth. I want to make a new document with year 0 **(red underlined in image attached)**, yet it always returns error.

My purpose is to save the document with the wrong value.

[image]

Here is the example document equal to image attached above (I've deleted unnecessary rows):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606e925e1c41330274706bbc"),
    "CREATED_DATE" : ISODate("2021-04-08T05:19:26.386+07:00"),
    "customer" : {
        "name" : "Customer Name"
        "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("0-12-29T16:19:26.386+07:00"),
        "gender" : "F",
    },
    "UPDATED_DATE" : ISODate("2021-11-10T23:35:23.187+07:00"),
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? You attempted and are getting an exception as expected.

Comment: @ray I'm trying to insert the document with the wrong value. I want to escape the exception.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the meaning of *wrong* ? Is that some specific test cases that you are executing? For your provided scenario of date, would `ISODate("0000-12-29...")` be an alternative to you?

Comment: The wrong meaning is the out of range year.  Here is a case related to this questions -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177590/iterating-through-pymongo-cursor-throws-invalidbson-year-is-out-of-range ...

I've tried using ISODate("0000-12-29...") also. It still returns the same error.

Comment: What is the exact command you used for the insertion? Can you also try running it in mongosh to see if it is related to the mongo client you use? I used a `insertOne` on my mongosh and it is just working fine. Here is the [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfyOR.png) after successful insert.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit, I've added example document on the desc.

Comment: @ray I insert it via Robo3T UI... Let me try it using insertOne.

Comment: @ray I can insert the year 0 value now. Thank you so much for helping!